# php:5-apache docker image no /etc/php/apache2/php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, docker, mongodb

I just pulled docker image php:5-apache and it runs well and all but there is no `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file so I can't add `extension=mongodb.so` even if it is installed with PECL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see what directories `php` looks for ini files in with the `--ini` flag. Here is an example on the `php:5-apache` image:

```
root@2ca6abaef312:/var/www/html# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

You can create an ini file in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d` with the changes you require.

Comment: Thanks, I added a `php.ini` file with just one line and it works.